# IPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

How to implement the Slidein slideout animation in my application.I have two view when i am clicking the root view the second view can be show like slidein and slideout

Answer (score 1):

[CATransition](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransition_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) with type `kCATransitionMoveIn` or `kCATransitionPush`

Code samples can be found in the `Related sample code` area.